# Guessing right pokemon from wrong spelling

Tags: python

I was trying to find if there is a way to get a close matching pokemon spelling from a wrong spelling.
Like
Hooppa returns hoopa or any closed matched pokemon.

And code in python or idea that can help me or any link related to it.

It is a bit similar to pokemon showdown dex search (js) but i am not able to find in python.

Comment: `difflib.closematches` would probably do what you wanted. just need to get a list of all pokemon

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_close_matches` function of [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) library

```py
import difflib

pokemon = ['pikachu', 'bulbasaur', 'charmander', 'squirtle', 'Hooppa']
input = input('Enter a pokemon: ')
closest_match = difflib.get_close_matches(input , pokemon)
print(closest_match)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fuzzy-wuzzy approach, It will give you string as well as scores, you can also build your logic upon them.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
str2Match = "apple inc"
strOptions = ["Apple Inc.","apple park","apple incorporated","iphone"]
Ratios = process.extract(str2Match,strOptions)
print(Ratios)
# You can also select the string with the highest matching percentage
highest = process.extractOne(str2Match,strOptions)
print(highest)
```

Output

```
[('Apple Inc.', 100), ('apple incorporated', 90), ('apple park', 67), ('iphone', 40)]
('Apple Inc.', 100)
```